# Trigger button click from another component button in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**I have component A button which displays form on click and component B button to show name. I want to trigger ComponentA button and display form when componentB button is clicked**

> componentA HTML

```
<section>
   <button (click)="toggle()">Click Here To Search</button>

 <div *ngIf="!showInput">
    <input type="text"/><br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
</section>
```

> componentA TS

```
  showInput = true; 
//...
  toggle() {
            this.showInput = !this.showInput;
           }
```

> componentB HTML

```
<button (click)="toggleText()">Add Fruit</button>

<div *ngIf="showText">Apple</div>
```

**I have created an example.Please use this link**

> [Example Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmtbsq)

Comment: Don't you want to show the name of the fruit or you just want to show the form if addFruit is clicked or want to show both simultaneously. As you are not clear what all exactly you want

Comment: want to show both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in that case make use of rxjs BehaviorSubject in a service, so that your entire application can make use of the variable and will update accordingly, like below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class Service {
  toggle: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  toggle$ = this.toggle.asObservable();
}
```

and in your my text component

```
toggleText() {
  this.showText = !this.showText;
  this.service.toggle.next(this.showText)
}
```

and in your FormsComponent

```
showInput;

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.toggle$.subscribe(
    toggle => this.showInput = toggle
  )
}
```

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsq3dj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice.ts)

Comment: Worked like a charm @Suryan. I have a question for you that when using NgRx, Is it the good approach using service ?

Comment: @JesseW sorry, don't have the experience of ngrx maybe other can help you out on this

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much @Suryan